# How to choose only one of the item to run from a list?

Tags: netlogo, patch

I am working on a model to simulate the development model. Now, there is a tricky problem returned in my codes:

```
to develop
grow-population
ask patches with [pcolor = grey][ask neighbors [set potential (potential + one-of [1 -1])]]
ask patches [ set new-potential (potential + sum [potential] of neighbors4) / 5 + one-of [1 -1] ]
ask patches [ set potential new-potential
              set development_patch patches with
                  [potential > threshold and urban? = 0 and fitness = 1 and population > 5]
             if any? development_patch 
                [let selected_patch one-of development_patch
                 ask selected_patch [set urban? 1
                                     set land-use "Urban"
                                     set pcolor blue  
                                    ]
               ]
            ]

tick
end
```

I randomly chose one of the item to run, but the result shows it runs a bunch of items. So, how should I just let one of the patches (selected_patch) change color in each tick? Thanks.

[image]
[image: This is the 1 tick result, it should not turn so many patches into blue color]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue stems from selecting your item inside a `ask patches[...]` call. This means that every single patch selects a patch that has to be turned blue. Moving the statement outside of the brackets fixes your issue

```
ask patches [ 
   set potential new-potential
   set development_patch patches with [potential > threshold and urban? = 0 and fitness = 1 and population > 5]
]

if any? development_patch [
     let selected_patch one-of development_patch
     ask selected_patch [
          set urban? 1
          set land-use "Urban"
          set pcolor blue  
     ]
]
```

Comment: Hi Leirs, thanks for your response. It is weird that, I did what you said, another issue arose ' tick cannot use in patch/turtle context, because tick is observer- only' . How can I fix this?

Comment: @user22570245 is development_patch a `patches-own` variable? From how your code looks, it assume it should be a `global` variable but if it is a patchspecific one, Netlogo will think the develop procedure is a patch procedure which cannot have `tick`

Comment: Hi Leirs, yes, all variables are patches-own. I removed the development_patch to globals, then it works!

Comment: Hi Leirs, I want to set a preference order for sorting paches, add new codes before the above like this:    ask patches with [pcolor = grey][ask neighbors [set potential (potential + one-of [1 -1])]]
  ask patches [ set new-potential (potential + sum [potential] of neighbors4) / 5 + one-of [1 -1] ]   . So, with that, the 'potential' now has an order, if there is a grey pcolor in neighbor4, which means this is the preference, and the potential value would be higher. My purpose is to fill the pcolor with blue first if it is neighboring to grey, and then others. Could you help me how to do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your goal is here. You want to colour multiple patches blue?

Comment: Hi Leirs, I updated the screenshot above, you may figure out there is a condition as color = grey. My purpose is when to develop, it should fill the pcolor which is close to the grey  patches first, then randomly one-of from others.

Comment: hi buz, did you receive the last comment? Tks.